# PostgreSQL on puppet

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I have created a postgres module, and basically it should run with the following order:

- Install postgres packages.
- Create the necessary directories (for logging, tablespaces).
- Dump scripts inside one of the directory.
- Start postgres service for the first time, initializing database.
- Copy over pg_hba.conf file.
- Reload postgresql service.
- Copy over postgresql.conf file.
- Restart postgresql service.
- Copy over .pgpass file.
- Copy over postgrespwd script.
- Run postgrespwd script.
- Create test role.
- Create data tablespace.
- Create index tablespace.
- Create testdb database.
- Alter testdb database.

The manifests is a bit too long so I pasted it here:
http://pastebin.com/2teEHvty

The module runs fine without error if I just test it on its own. But if I were to run it together with the rest of other modules (after a fresh installation of an OS), it hit an error at the creation of test role. I just have to rerun puppet again, and all is good.

Error from puppet.log:

```
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db01/index]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db01/data]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/pg_log]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/backup]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/backup/pg_dump]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/backup/wal_archive]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/scripts]/ensure (notice): created
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/scripts/pgbackup_all.sh]/ensure (notice): defined content as '{md5}7489ef8bb44a57d609cfbd0bd572db15'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/scripts/delPgsqlLog.sh]/ensure (notice): defined content as '{md5}d864f85098b5fee53076885ed3207604'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:00 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/db02/scripts/backup_scripts.sh]/ensure (notice): defined content as '{md5}bedeed6d0c7262d3b0da6360b22c978a'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:05 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/Service[postgresql]/ensure (notice): ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:05 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf]/content (notice): content changed '{md5}825a0fdcb66009d65b7ed6eb4941a935' to '{md5}a2caff21e5131905b185b1f6154556be'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:05 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/root/.pgpass]/ensure (notice): defined content as '{md5}d7f17ce929c821e0647fe7ea502168bc'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:06 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/File[/tmp/postgrespwd]/ensure (notice): defined content as '{md5}239bfd90c3cd63c4e8feca4065e7887a'
Tue Mar 17 12:02:06 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[set-postgres-pwd] (notice): Triggered 'refresh' from 2 events
Tue Mar 17 12:02:06 +0800 2015 /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[create-test-role]/returns (err): change from notrun to 0 failed: psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres  -c "CREATE ROLE test LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md5xxxxxxx' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE RE
```

Rerun puppet:

```
# puppet agent -t
info: Caching catalog for test.playground.local
info: Applying configuration version '1426498915'
--- /etc/zypp/repos.d/suselocal.repo    2015-03-16 17:47:38.000000000 +0800
+++ /tmp/puppet-file20150316-10778-ah5kgh-0 2015-03-16 17:52:27.000000000 +0800
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
 [myrepo]
 name=myrepo
+baseurl=http://192.168.0.10/sles/repo
 enabled=1
 autorefresh=1
-baseurl=http://192.168.0.10/sles/repo
-type=rpm-md
 gpgcheck=0
info: FileBucket adding {md5}6d7b895fa91e9633790fc518fef12896
info: /Stage[main]/Myrepo/File[/etc/zypp/repos.d/suselocal.repo]: Filebucketed /etc/zypp/repos.d/suselocal.repo to puppet with sum 6d7b895fa91e9633790fc518fef12896
notice: /Stage[main]/Myrepo/File[/etc/zypp/repos.d/suselocal.repo]/content: content changed '{md5}6d7b895fa91e9633790fc518fef12896' to '{md5}ca60c4d8ce7e28506bbdb440618d4c4d'
notice: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[create-test-role]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[create-tbs-data]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[create-tbs-index]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[create-db-tesdb]/returns: executed successfully
info: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[create-db-testdb]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[alter-db-phisprod]
notice: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[alter-db-testdb]/returns: executed successfully
notice: /Stage[main]/Postgres/Exec[alter-db-testdb]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
notice: Finished catalog run in 34.85 seconds
```

Content of postgrespwd:
    #!/bin/sh

```
su - postgres -c "psql" << EOF
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'xxxx';
EOF
```

Content of .pgpass:

```
127.0.0.1:5432:*:postgres:xxxx
127.0.0.1:5432:postgres:test:yyyy
127.0.0.1:5432:testdb:test:yyyy
```

My questions:

1. Why does it fail during the first run?
2. How do I prevent the `alter-db-testdb` from being executed everytime I run puppet? It is harmless I supposed, but I would prefer it to be executed only one time upon the creation of the database.

Thanks.

Comment: General comment: With this many `exec` resources, you definitely want to write a shell script instead that gets invoked by Puppet when there is something to do, through a single `exec` resource.

Comment: Thanks @FelixFrank, think I'd go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing (1), have you checked the logs? Also, are you aware of puppet modules that can setup and configure [postgresql](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/postgresql)?

For (2), this kind of requirement has come up often enough that I've developed a puppet module ([cpitman/database_schema](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/cpitman/database_schema)) that uses a database migration tool like [flyway](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/commandline.html) to only apply migrations when updates need to be applied.

Comment: yes I'm aware of the puppet modules, but at the time I was new with puppet that I felt trying to understand the module will take a longer time rather than writing one of my own with a bunch of execs. Well, that's before I started to realize about all of the erb, variable scoping, relationships, ordering and stuff. Lol. I have checked the logs, not much of help though. I have posted it up there. The log was just half way. It stopped right there. I wonder why.

Comment: Well I do remember checking the logs, but I don't remember anything relevant. Maybe when I have the time I'll try to reproduce the error. For the moment it's running well after I moved the bunch of execs into a script. Thanks.

Comment: Wonder why everytime I mentioned your name like this @ChrisPitman at the beginning of the line, it didn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changes you've triggered made in the first run have triggered a refresh of the service, but it hasn't actually happened at the point where you try to create the test role.  I'm guessing that the change in the root password might be the problem, with `/root/.pgpass` beign out of sync with the actual situation until the postgres service is restarted.  You might be able to resolve this with some resource dependencies to change the order things are done in, or you might just accept it's taking two runs to complete setup.  Or perhaps there's a way to trigger the service restart immediately when key changes like the root pw are made?

2) Your pastebin info has disappeared now (which is problematic for the ongoing value of this question to other people), but I can see from what's here that it was an exec resource.  Presumably you need a `refreshonly => true` on the exec, and a  `notify`, `subscribe`, or `~>` arrow linking the exec to the resource which creates the db.